# np.squeeze() used in implementing cost function and gradient

Tags: python, numpy

Below are the codes to calculate cost function and gradient in order to classify an image, based on the Coursera Deep Learning course.

After calculating the cost as below

```
cost = -np.sum(Y*np.log(A) + (1-Y)*np.log(1-A)) / m
```

The `cost.shape` is

```
()
```

Then what is the purpose of the below operation

```
cost = np.squeeze(cost)
```

In the function

```
def propagate(w, b, X, Y):
    """
    Implement the cost function and its gradient for the propagation

    Arguments:
    w -- weights, a numpy array of size (num_px * num_px * 3, 1)
    b -- bias, a scalar
    X -- data of size (num_px * num_px * 3, number of examples)
    Y -- true "label" vector (containing 0 if non-cat, 1 if cat) of size (1, number of examples)

    Return:
    cost -- negative log-likelihood cost for logistic regression
    dw -- gradient of the loss with respect to w, thus same shape as w
    db -- gradient of the loss with respect to b, thus same shape as b

    """
    m = X.shape[1]

    # FORWARD PROPAGATION (FROM X TO COST)
    A = sigmoid(np.dot(w.T, X) + b)          # compute activation
    cost = -np.sum(Y*np.log(A) + (1-Y)*np.log(1-A)) / m      # compute cost

    # BACKWARD PROPAGATION (TO FIND GRAD)
    dw = np.dot(X, (A-Y).T) / m
    db = np.sum(A-Y) / m

    assert(dw.shape == w.shape)
    assert(db.dtype == float)
    cost = np.squeeze(cost)
    assert(cost.shape == ())

    grads = {"dw": dw,
             "db": db}

    return grads, cost
```

Answer (score 3):

`np.squeeze` is used to remove the axis with the Singleton element in the `numpy.ndarray`.  For example, if you have a numpy array `a` of shape `(n,m,1,p)`, then `np.squeeze(a)` will make the shape as `(n,m,p)`, reducing the third axis as it had only one element.

Here, `cost` should be a single value. Though it is an `np.ndarray` of shape `()`, after computing itself, an extra step `np.squeeze(a)` is explicitly taken to ensure that if it does contain any redundant axis, then remove it.

Answer (score 0):

```
# GRADED FUNCTION: propagate

def propagate(w, b, X, Y):
    """
    Implement the cost function and its gradient for the propagation explained above

    Arguments:
    w -- weights, a numpy array of size (num_px * num_px * 3, 1)
    b -- bias, a scalar
    X -- data of size (num_px * num_px * 3, number of examples)
    Y -- true "label" vector (containing 0 if non-cat, 1 if cat) of size (1, number of examples)

    Return:
    cost -- negative log-likelihood cost for logistic regression
    dw -- gradient of the loss with respect to w, thus same shape as w
    db -- gradient of the loss with respect to b, thus same shape as b
    
    Tips:
    - Write your code step by step for the propagation. np.log(), np.dot()
    """
    
    m = X.shape[1]
    
    # FORWARD PROPAGATION (FROM X TO COST)
    ### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 2 lines of code)
    A =   sigmoid(np.dot(w.T,X) + b)                                 # compute activation
    print(A.shape)
    print(Y.shape)
    cost = -1*np.sum((np.multiply(Y,np.log(A)) +np.multiply((1-Y), np.log(1 - A)) ))
    print(cost.shape)# compute cost
    ### END CODE HERE ###
    
    # BACKWARD PROPAGATION (TO FIND GRAD)
    ### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 2 lines of code)
    dw = 1/m*np.dot(X, (A - Y).T)
    db = 1/m*np.sum(A - Y)
    
    ### END CODE HERE ###

    assert(dw.shape == w.shape)
    assert(db.dtype == float)
    cost = np.squeeze(cost)
    assert(cost.shape == ())
    
    grads = {"dw": dw,
             "db": db}
    
    return grads, cost
```